# UIAccelerometer Stop Problem

Tags: iphone

How to Detect UIAccelerometer stop event when user stop moving the iPhone.
So how to detect the stopping of moving the phone

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3669-uiaccelerometer-angle-instant-velocity.html)'s a discussion on how to calculate instant velocity with a certain degree of accuracy. When such instant velocity raises to a value above 0, set a flag, and if after increasing, it will eventually decrease back to 0, if you have the flag set it means that the device did move, and now has stopped.